# Code navigation in VSCode doesn't work on external *.js files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Update: I found a writeup
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/highcharts-typescript-declarations
I suspect that will work.

I have some script tags in head of index.html

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="space.css">
    <script src="../highcharts/code/highcharts.src.js" defer ></script>
    <script src="../highcharts/code/highcharts-3d.src.js" defer ></script>
    <script src="../highcharts/code/modules/exporting.src.js" defer ></script>
    <script src="../highcharts/code/modules/export-data.src.js" defer ></script>
    <script src="../highcharts/code/modules/accessibility.src.js" defer ></script>
    <script src="./space.js" defer ></script>
</head>
```

in `space.js`, I'd like hover and code navigation to work, but it doesn't (hover gives type 'any'.  I added a jsconfig.json which didn't seem to help:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    }
}
```

I tried:

```js
/// <reference path="./code/highcharts.src.js" />
```

I tried annotating my code:

```js
// Set up the chart
/**
 * @param chart Highcharts.Chart
 */
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container',{
    chart: {
        margin: 200,
        type: 'scatter3d',
```

.  The JSDoc did tell echo back that `chart` was the type I declared it to be, but no more.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: pretty sure you need to install corresponding packages with type declarations as NPM development dependencies.